# Can you prove a psychological theory on a one-person research design?

Tags: methodology, experimental-psychology, statistics

Famous psychologists have proven their theories on a few subjects (really small sample sizes, like n = 3). Yet, now, we are taught that to prove any psychological theory right, we need to gather data from many subjects (with tongue-in-cheek: above 30). But seriously... (here's the question I'm asking):

**Q:** is it somehow unscientific or wrong to only show a psychological theory with so small sample size such as n = 1 (one person, but many measurements on him/her)?

Comment: Which psychologists are you referring to? I'm aware of several who *used* just a few subjects to introduce theories which then turned out to hold some substance, but not of any who *proved* (read "justified") anything in the proper statistical sense...

Comment: @DavidCian Skinner, Piaget...

Comment: Can you give an example of a proven theory in psychology? I am afraid you are actually speaking about psychologists who have constructed scientific hypotheses, not ones who have proven anything.